# Included php file don't work after Ajax refresh

Tags: php, ajax

I got a php page `results.php` that display personal files per users from an S3 folder. In `results.php` I have `include 'results-core.php';`that as for the name, retrieves datas from the s3 bucket and store them in arrays called by `results.php`, that is contained in a  page, `page.php` :

```
        page.php

        [..]
        <div id="primary" class="content-area col-md-9">
        <main id="main" class="post-wrap" role="main">
        <?php
        $session = $_GET['sh_session'];
            include 'results.php';
        ?>
          </main><!-- #main -->       
            </div>  
        [..]
```

I refresh the `results.php` of the `main id="main"`using this script on the sidebar (called by user click in the main):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    parent.$('#main').load('results.php');   
})
```

and the main reloads, but it stays empty. No data is retrieved. That's weird because when I access the page, everything works correctly, but not after the script refresh the main.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> parent.$('#main').load('results.php');
> ```

Look at the URL you are requesting — `results.php`.

There is no query string! `$_GET['sh_session']` will therefore be empty.

If you want to have `$_GET['sh_session']` to have a value then you have to give it one.

```
parent.$('#main').load('results.php?sh_session=foo');
```

Comment: as far as I know queries cannot be sent through `.load` , but however I just tried and it don't work.

Comment: `load` expects to be given a URL. URLs can have query strings. I tested it. It works: https://i.imgur.com/IcOteaL.png

Comment: UPDATE I tried to add an echo `"hi";` at the very begin of the `results.php` and it don't show up too. So it seems that it refresh the div with... Nothing?!?

Comment: UPDATE BIS Nothing was showing up because of the `MAIN` element and not `DIV`, so I changed it to a `DIV`. So probably `load()` doesn't work with `MAINs` but just with `DIVs`. Now the `echo "hi";` I tried to add shows up along with the message: `hi Notice: Undefined variable: session in /srv/bin...`